# "I would have selected you even without a recommendation."

Tags: questions, interrogatives

> I would have selected you even without a recommendation.

What would be the question to this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of questions, or even just statements could prompt this reply:

Questions:

- Would you have selected me?
- Would you have selected me without a recommendation?

Statements:

- I didn't think you would select me.
- I didn't have a recommendation.

All of these, and probably others too, could prompt the reply:

> "I would have selected you even without a recommendation".

Comment: It need not be a reply at all. It is just a statement.